# My redirects aren't working in .htaccess for one site. They are working on other sites and the statements appear to be the exact same

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have multiple hosts configured on MAMP Pro.  I set them all up the same.  I have redirects working on one site and not on the other.  Below is my .htaccess file contents for the site that's not working.  After doing a stare and compare the rules appear to be declared with the same syntax.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/register.php$ https://mydomain.test/register/ [L,R=301,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue.  The issue is that I have a slash before register.php and that file is not within a folder.  The URL is www.mydomain.com/register.php.  If it were www.mydomain.com/folder/register.php then this would work.

Instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/register.php$ https://mydomain.test/register/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)register.php$ https://mydomain.test/register/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: It should probably rather be `RewriteRule ^register\.php$`, otherwise you’d still be catching any requests that _end with_ `register.php` (because of `(.*)` allowing _anything_ before it, zero or more times), and the `.` also needs to be escaped if it is supposed to mean “dot” only.

Comment: I do want to catch it with anything before in this particular case.  It's working without the escaped dot (on MAMP) but I will update that to be safe.  Thanks so much for your input.  I appreciate it!